# How would I go about writing a very simplistic parser for java code in python?

Tags: java, python, parsing

I'm trying to write a very barebones parser for java code in python.

Basically what I'd need are two methods: handle_keyword(keyword) and handle_operator(operator) which would get automatically called when keywords and operators are encountered.

I'd also like a third method called handle_other(text) which would handle any substring in the file which was not a keyword or operator.

text, keyword, and operator in the above methods would all be strings

I'd like to know if Python has some sort of built in for something like this, or if there's any parsing algorithms/techniques that anyone can recommend. I've looked at python's HTML parser but I'm not sure I can use similar methods for java code. If there's already an existing library that would be even better/

Comment: The best way I know of to do this is using regex. Just like all code text editors.

Comment: Do you need something that often works or something that always works? In the latter case you need to write at least a real lexer for Java that handles things like unicode escape, comments, strings, etc. A regex is not powerful enough to handle all cases.

Answer (score 3):

Just use ANTLR with the Java grammar and specify Python as the target language.

Comment: Just to add that since he wants only keywords or operators or other tokens, that he only needs the lexer and not the language grammar. But since the lexer is also part of the Java grammar in ANTLR I've +1'ed